# Starting method after screen has loaded wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm getting familiar with python / wxpython. 
I've created a class for the panel / grid.
But I want to "paint" the grid and only after all is loaded / shown, I want to start to run a method / function to count running processes in Windows. Code snippet:

```
    self.sb.SetStatusText('Initialising application...')
    self.SetTitle('Computer Check v0.1')
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

    self.onStart()

def onStart(self):

        self.sb.SetStatusText('Counting processes')     
        count = 0
        for process in c.Win32_Process():
            count +=1
        self.sb.SetStatusText('Found '+str(count)+' running processes')
```

but it looks like things are following eachother to fast, meaning that the application is being painted and the "onstart()" is already running...

Another thing is that the application "hangs" during the onstart(), it seems quite heavy to use the WMI...or maybe the code is just crap from my side ;-)

Can't find an event to use to initiate the onstart after the application has loaded. 
How to do this in a proper way?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wx.CallAfter to run a callable when the wx event loop "has free time", or wx.CallLater to run something after some period of time.

```
wx.CallAfter(self.onStart)
```

I do not know if Win32_Process takes a long time, if so, it will certainly block the UI. The best thing would be to start a new thread to perform the computation (Win32_Process), and then for example wx.CallAfter to update the UI. Remember, you may not update the UI from other threads.

When your thread calculates the value, you can for example

```
def thread_run_function(self):
    # perform the calculation...
    wx.CallAfter(self.update_ui, calculated_value)

def update_ui(self, calculated_value):
    self.some_widget.SetLabel("Value: %s" % calculated_value)
```

Or:

```
def thread_run_function(self):
    # perform the calculation...
    self.calculated_value = calculated_value
    wx.CallAfter(self.update_ui)

def update_ui(self):
    self.some_widget.SetLabel("Value: %s" % self.calculated_value)
```

Comment: So I can't pass the outcome...e.g. 280 processes back to the UI?

Comment: You must somehow pass it into the main thread. For example by using a member variable or with CallAfter. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Super, I'll give it a try!